# how can I sort array with np.sort()

Tags: python, numpy

I have `A = np.array([43, 66, 34, 55, 78, 105, 2])`
I need to sort the A[i] by increase if number is divisible by 2
Answer will be `array([ 43,   2,  34,  55,  66, 105,  78])`
How can I do this using np.sort()?

Answer (score 4):

You could use boolean indexing and set sorted values in place:

```
idx = A % 2 == 0
A[idx] = np.sort(A[idx])
```